# Elastic matchQuery for name

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elastic field which contains a user name, eg. my name would contain `john doe`.

I am trying to create a match query to be able to find my name by phrases like:

- `john d`
- `john do`
- `doe`

My query:

```
      {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [
            {
              "match" : {
                "keywords" : {
                  "query" : "john do",
                  "operator" : "AND",
                  "prefix_length" : 0,
                  "max_expansions" : 50,
                  "minimum_should_match" : "50%",
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

the problem is that `john` and `john do` will not find anything because of the `AND` operator. If I switch to `OR`, searching for `john doe` will actually select every `john` in the database and my last name will not be even at the top result.

How should the query be formed for such search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [match phrase prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html), tested it on below samples and seems to be working fine according to your use-case.

**Sample documents**

```
{
    "name" :  "john doe"
}

{
    "name" :  "john"
    
}

{
    "name" :  "john do"

}
```

**Search query using match phrase prefix**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "name": {
        "query": "john d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Vojtěch ofcourse, Its working on all your search terms mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Vojtěch one more thing, this would not require changes in index settings and mappings and don't require you to reindex all documents

Answer (score 1):

I think edge_ngrams should work in this case.
Please try the following:

Set the index to use edge_ngrams as index analyzer.

```
PUT test 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "custom_edge_ngram":
        {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
          "custom_analyzer":{
            "tokenizer":"standard",
            "filter":[
              "lowercase",
              "custom_edge_ngram"]
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then query the index using the following query:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": 
      {
        "query":"vojtech k",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EXPLAINATION:**

The edge ngram index analyzer will generate ngrams with min length 1 and max 10 for your name field in the index

You can check the tokens using this:

```
GET test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
  "text": ["vojtech knyttl"]
}
```

When you search using the match query it will find vojtech and k as ngrams in your doc.

My test cases
vojtech adams, vojtech knyttl, vojtech, joe knyttl

If I search vojtech knyttl it returns 1 result.

If I search vojtech I get vojtech adams, vojtech knyttl, vojtech

If I search vojteck k I get vojtech knyttl

If I search knyttl I get vojtech knyttl, joe knyttl

Comment: Updated the answer with my test cases. Is this what you are looking for?